# Elasticsearch 7.9 forward slashes

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 7.9.1 and want to search for "/abc" (including the forward slash) in the field name "Path", such as such as in "mysite.com/abc/xyz". Here's the index template, but doesn't work:

"Path": {
"type": "text",
"index": false
}

What did I do wrong? Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: They keep changing the syntax so not sure of the latest syntax for not_analyzed text fields so we can search for the forward slashes in the URL. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

They changed the syntax for "not analyzed" text [only once](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) (in ES 5), from

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

to

```
{
   "type": "keyword"
}
```

If you want special characters like `/` to not be removed at indexing time during analysis, you should use `keyword` instead of `text`.

Moreover, if your intent is to search within URL, you should prefer the [`wildcard` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) or keep using text but use an appropriate [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) that splits your URL into parts.

If you upgrade to 7.11, you could also have access to the [URI parts ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/uri-parts-processor.html) that does all the job for you.

Comment: Thanks @val. I updated the template with the following:
"Path": {
  "type": "keyword",
  "ignore_above": 512
},
but when I search for Path:"/abc" the result only shows (highlights) those docs with "abc" and it still ignored the forward slash "/". Any further idea? Thanks.